# How do I interpolate a missing area in a 2D image in python using Gaussians?

Tags: python, image, scipy, interpolation

I have been looking for some version of the answer to this question in many places, but I feel like the indexing is just getting the better of me. I have a 2D Gaussian image, which has a grayscale value as appears below

#visual examination shows that the area with the slit is row 169 to 185 and column 0 to 179. below is code to load the image from a tif file ('Cropped.tif') and also a script that converts from rgb to grayscale.

```
def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])

#plot the  grayscale image
plt.title("Image Grayscale")
plt.xlabel("X pixels")
plt.ylabel("Y Pixels Label")
image_unprocessed=mpimg.imread('Cropped.tif')
plt.imshow(rgb2gray(image_unprocessed))
plt.show()


image_grayscale=rgb2gray(image_unprocessed)
```

[image]

Now I want to interpolate in that small slit that appears in the middle. . What I have essentially done is set the values in the slit to nan manally. The image itself is image_grayscale which is a354x342 numpy array for which I want to interpolate in region [169:195,0:195]. My mwe is as follows

```
from scipy import interpolate
image_grayscale[169:195,0:195]=np.nan
x = np.arange(0, image_grayscale.shape[1])
y = np.arange(0, image_grayscale.shape[0])
image_grayscale=np.ma.masked_invalid(image_grayscale)
xx,yy=np.meshgrid(x,y)
x1=xx[~image_grayscale.mask]
y1=yy[~image_grayscale.mask]
new_imagegreyscale=image_grayscale[~image_grayscale.mask]

GD1 = interpolate.griddata((x1, y1), new_imagegreyscale.ravel(),
                          (xx, yy),
                             method='linear')

plt.title("Image interpolated")
plt.xlabel("X pixels")
plt.ylabel("Y Pixels Label")
plt.imshow(GD1)
plt.show()
```

Which returns the following image, which isn't bad but definitely isn't perfect, you can see that there are imperfections near the middle which I want to get rid of

[image]

However, I feel like if I could just let the interpolator know to use a gaussian fit instead of a linear or cubic fit then the interpolated image may be better, but I am not sure about how this would change the syntax. I can see that scipy.interpolate has a lot of different interpolators but I am unsure of 1) which algorithm would be best suited for this case 2) how the syntax of implementing that algorithm differs from what I have above. I saw that the [RBFInterpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RBFInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.RBFInterpolator) has an option to use gaussian basis funcions, but when I try the RBF interpolater as above

```
from scipy.interpolate import RBFInterpolator
image_grayscale[169:195,0:195]=np.nan
x = np.arange(0, image_grayscale.shape[1])
y = np.arange(0, image_grayscale.shape[0])
image_grayscale=np.ma.masked_invalid(image_grayscale)
xx,yy=np.meshgrid(x,y)
x1=xx[~image_grayscale.mask]
y1=yy[~image_grayscale.mask]
new_imagegreyscale=image_grayscale[~image_grayscale.mask]

GD1 = RBFInterpolator((x1, y1), new_imagegreyscale.ravel(),
                          (xx, yy))

plt.title("Image interpolated")
plt.xlabel("X pixels")
plt.ylabel("Y Pixels Label")
plt.imshow(GD1)
plt.show()
```

I get the value error "Expected the first axis of `d` to have length 2.". I can see that this is a syntax issue but I have been really struggling at making any sense of the correct syntax. Sorry if this has been asked before but the other threads I found on 2D interpolation didn't quite give me the clarity I was looking for.

Comment: Can't reproduce: `NameError: name 'image_grayscale' is not defined` - Can you add a snippet that generates an appropriate initial image?